# Get the zoomed frame of UIScrollView relative to original size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView and added a UIView inside it, when I zoom it, is it possible to get the CGRect of the zoomed frame in relation to the original frame?

E.g. i have 800x600 frame, then i zoomed to {{50, 60}, {100, 100}} is it possible to programmatically get the zoomed frame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually use the following method (added to the custom UIScrollView category):

```
- (CGRect) visibleRect{
    CGRect visibleRect;

    visibleRect.origin = self.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = self.bounds.size;

    visibleRect.origin.x /= self.zoomScale;
    visibleRect.origin.y /= self.zoomScale;
    visibleRect.size.width /= self.zoomScale;
    visibleRect.size.height /= self.zoomScale;
    return visibleRect;
}
```

Comment: Would appreciate if you leave some comment on my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with @Vladimir solution is that it displays visibleRect wrong if viewForZoom is smaller than ScrollView bounds. So I came up with this solution.

```
- (CGRect) zoomedFrame{
    CGRect zoomedFrame;

    zoomedFrame.origin = self.contentOffset;
    zoomedFrame.origin.x -= zoomingView.frame.origin.x;
    zoomedFrame.origin.y -= zoomingView.frame.origin.y;
    zoomedFrame.size = self.contentSize;
    return zoomedFrame;
}
```

`zoomingView` is a view that returns `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method.
`bounds` are bounds of scrollView.

---

**So there are two cases:**

1. When the `zoomingView` is smaller than `bounds`, `contentOffset` reflect not the top-left corner of content view, but some strange shift of content view relative to the center of `bounds`. And `zoomingView.frame.origin` has normal values as if `zoomingView` were in the center of `bounds`. (*this happens if you try to shrink the zoomingView more than `minimulScale`*)
2. When the `zoomingView` is bigget than `bounds`, `zoomingView.frame.origin` has strange values like this:

   > {-6.15367e-06, 3.98168e-06}

   And `contentOffset` shows what it [should](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset).

---

So all that compensate each other as I showed in my code.